# How to persist token when user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native web app and a user can login. But if the main page is refreshed after a user has logged in. the screen returns to the login screen.

So this is my login service:

```
import { removeToken, retrieveToken } from "../authentication/token";

import { API_URL } from "@env";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export const loginRequest = async (email, password) => {    
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/user/token/`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password,
        }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("Token", data.token);

        return true;
    } else {
        throw new Error(data.token);
    }
 };
}
```

and login context:

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [token, setToken] = useState(AsyncStorageLib.getItem("Token"));
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const toast = useToast();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (token) {
            AsyncStorageLib.getItem("Token");
        }
        
    });


    const onLogin = (email, password) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        loginRequest(email, password)
            .then((u) => {
                setUser(u);

                setToken(u.token);
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                setIsLoading(false);
                toast.show("Email of wachtwoord incorrect. Probeer het nog eens", { type: "warning" });
            });
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{
                isAuthenticated: !!user,
                isLoading,
                error,
                user,               
                onLogin,
                
            }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Question: how to persist token when page is refreshed?

Comment: Could be that AsyncStorage.getItem is asynchronous and cannot be directly used in useState because useState does not support promises

Comment: @Christoph. How to resolve this then?

Comment: Your Token is persistent, you're saving it here `await AsyncStorage.setItem("Token", data.token)` but you're not using it. Revalidate the token in `useEffect` and use `setUser` if its successful. Otherwise `user` will always be `null` on a refresh.

Comment: Use useEffect to retrieve the token from AsyncStorage, once the token is retrieved, update the token state

Comment: It's a web application. Use cookie authentication + XSRF protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AsyncStorageLib.getItem` function probably returns a promise then token state initial value never would be as expected

with a little help of useEffect you can initial the token state as below:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorageLib.getItem("Token").then((t) => setToken(t))
  },[]);
```

this code might work for you:

```
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const toast = useToast();

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorageLib.getItem("Token").then((t) => setToken(t))
  },[]);

  const onLogin = (email, password) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      loginRequest(email, password)
          .then((u) => {
              setUser(u);

              setToken(u.token);
              setIsLoading(false);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
              setIsLoading(false);
              toast.show("Email of wachtwoord incorrect. Probeer het nog eens", { type: "warning" });
          });
  };

  return (
      <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{
              isAuthenticated: !!user || !!token,
              isLoading,
              error,
              user,               
              onLogin,
              
          }}>
          {children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```